# Determine if sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k!b^k}{(a+kb)\cdots (a+1\cdot b)}$ diverge

Tags: summation

This is a special case, so we assume that $a>b$ and I need to figure out if the sum 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k!b^k}{(a+kb)\cdots (a+1\cdot b)}$
diverge to infinity or not. I have tried a lot of things without succes so a hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\lambda := a/b > 1$ you can rewrite your series as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k!}{(\lambda + k)\cdots (\lambda +1)} =: \sum_k a_k.
$$
Since
$$
n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} - 1\right) = 
n \left( \frac{\lambda+n+1}{n+1} - 1\right) = n \frac{\lambda}{n+1} \to \lambda > 1,
$$
by [Raabe's criterion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Raabe_criterion) the series is convergent.

Comment: And what if $b<0$?

Comment: Sorry, I have implicitly assumed that $b>0$. Anyway, I think that a similar approach can be used provided that $\lambda := a/b$ is not a negative integer.